# Remove Prestashop orphan images not stored in DB

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to clean a shop running Prestashop, actually 1.7, since many years.

With [this script](https://github.com/melikslab/Clean-unused-images-prestashop) I removed all the images in the DB not connected to any product.

But there are many files not listed in the DB. For example, actually I have 5 image sizes in settings, so new products shows 6 files in the folder (the 5 above and the imageID.jpg file) but some old product had up to 18 files. Many of these old products have been deleted but in the folder I still find all the other formats, like "2026-small-cart.jpg".

So I tried creating a script to loop in folders, check image files in it and verify if that id_image is stored in the DB.
If not, I can delete the file.
It works but obviously the loop is huge and it stops working as long as I change the starting path folder.

I've tried to reduce the DB queries storing some data (to delete all the images with the same id with a single DB query), but it still crashes as I change the starting path.
It only works with two nested loops (really few...).

Here is the code. Any idea for a better way to get the result?

Thanks!

```
$shop_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'; 
include('./config/config.inc.php');
include('./init.php');
$image_folder = 'img/p/';


$image_folder = 'img/p/2/0/3/2/'; // TEST, existing product
$image_folder = 'img/p/2/0/2/6/'; // TEST, product deleted from DB but files in folder
//$image_folder = 'img/p/2/0/2/'; // test, not working...
$scan_dir = $shop_root.$image_folder;
// will check only images...
global $imgExt;
$imgExt = array("jpg","png","gif","jpeg");
// to avoid multiple queries for the same image id...
global $lastID;
global $delMode;

echo "<h1>Examined folder: $image_folder</h1>\r\n";


function checkFile($scan_dir,$name) {
    global $lastID;
    global $delMode;
    $path = $scan_dir.$name;
    $ext = substr($name,strripos($name,".")+1);
    // if is an image and file name starts with a number
    if (in_array($ext,$imgExt) && (int)$name>0){
        // avoid extra queries...
        if ($lastID == (int)$name) {
            $inDb = $lastID;
        } else {
            $inDb = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'image WHERE id_image ='.((int) $name)); 
            $lastID = (int)$name;
            $delMode = $inDb;
        }
        // if haven't found an id_product in the DB for that id_image 
        if ($delMode<1){
            echo "- $path has no related product in the DB I'll DELETE IT<br>\r\n";
            //unlink($path);
        } 
    }
}


function checkDir($scan_dir,$name2) {
    echo "<h3>Elements found in the folder <i>$scan_dir$name2</i>:</h3>\r\n";
    $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($scan_dir.$name2.'/'), array('..', '.'))); 
    foreach ($files as $key => $name) {
        $path = $scan_dir.$name;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            // new loop in the subfolder
            checkDir($scan_dir,$name);  
        } else {
            // is a file, I'll check if must be deleted
            checkFile($scan_dir,$name);
        }
    }
}


checkDir($scan_dir,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create two files with lists of images.

The first file is the result of a query from your database of every image file referenced in your data.

```
mysql -BN -e "select distinct id_image from ${DB}.${DB_PREFIX}image" > all_image_ids
```

(set the shell variables for DB and DB_PREFIX first)

The second file is every image file currently in your directories. Include only files that start with a digit and have an image extension.

```
find img/p -name '[0-9]*.{jpg,png,gif,jpeg}' > all_image_files
```

For each filename, check if it's in the list of image ids. If not, then output the command to delete the file.

```
cat all_image_files | while read filename ; do
  # strip the directory name and convert filename to an integer value
  b=$(basename $filename)
  image_id=$((${b/.*/}))
  grep -q "^${image_id}$" all_image_ids || echo "rm ${filename}"
done > files_to_delete
```

Read the file `files_to_delete` to visually check that the list looks right. Then run that file as a shell script:

```
sh files_to_delete
```

Note I have not tested this solution, but it should give you something to experiment with.

Comment: Hi, sorry to haven't answered... I actually don't have ssh access to the server but thanks for the hints, duplicating the data or obtaining the access, it should do its job!
Thanks